# UTM tracking for the Social Share Buttons: Facebook, Pinterest

Tags: facebook, google-analytics, pinterest, socialshare

all.

I want to add `utm_` parameters to all my social share buttons. I successfully included the parameters into the Twitter and G+ without any problems. But have a lot of problems with Facebook and Pinterest.

Pinterest strip any `utm_` parameters.
Facebook uses a canonical URL instead of I provided.

Solutions I was tried:

1) using an URL shortener bit.ly. Pinterest [doesn't allow to use it](https://en.help.pinterest.com/entries/21436306-why-is-my-pin-or-site-blocked-for-spam-or-inappropriate-content). Facebook still use the canonical URL instead of one I provided

2) Use the `fb_ref` for the Facebook. We use Wordpress VIP hosting and this hosting strips any parameters from facebook.

3) Rename the `utm_` parameters to `utm`. It was fixed the problem but I want to keep all my tracking info consistent.

Any ideas? Thanks

**UPDATE 12/21/13**

I want to have the following. Scenario:

1) user shares the content from my site (`http://example.com/url/?utm_campaign=onsitesharebutton`)

2) user's friend goes to Social Network, for example Pinterest, and see this Pin

3) user's friend clicks on this Pin and goes to my site. When he goes to my site, I wanted to have the utm_* parameters in the URL, ie `http://example.com/url/?utm_campaign=onsitesharebutton`. In this way I will know that this user arrived through a certain source or overall marketing channel as part of a certain campaign

Problems:

1) Pinterest [strips `UTM_*` parameters from the my URLs](http://www.quora.com/Pinterest/Does-Pinterest-strip-UTM-parameters-from-the-URLs-of-images-that-have-been-pinned-If-so-is-there-a-workaround-to-get-this-data-in-Analytics-1)

2) Facebook uses canonical URL to share and ignores my `UTM_*` parameters

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are doing. Presumably your social share buttons redirect users to social sites, where you can't track them with GA anyway. More likely you are looking for _trackSocial (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiSocialTracking), a method that shows share button clicks in the acquisition->social->plugin reports. Google+ is tracked automatically.

Comment: You can try to use Google Analytics campaign tracking on social media. But Google Analytics knows who the major social networks are and they have a whole social report section just for them. If you want to track when the buttons are clicked you can use _trackSocial or another event. I've done a lot of work on this. It is doable but not necessarily fun. Facebook changed its buttons recently and this has confused and annoyed me. I now prefer the Share button to the Like button when it comes to Facebook. Of course I prefer Twitter and even Pinterest over Facebook...

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I had to provide an example. I'll update my answer in 1 hour

Answer (score 0):

I still would like to change a few things about the Facebook Like / Share button and Google+ button seems to sometimes have issues in Safari, but [I successfully track](http://blog.muschamp.ca/2013/10/02/tracking-social-media-button-clicks-in-google-analytics/) likes, pins, +1s, tweets, and even LinkedIn using a variety of techniques.

Facebooks recent changes to their buttons just confused me. I had everything working and then they change all.js or whatever the JavaScript is you must use. They also changed the colors and size. I wasted a lot of time on this and I'm still not happy but I do track everything carefully in Google Analytics.